# Android NDK gives undefined reference to various existing methods

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-code

I've defined my Android.mk as follow:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := optplugin.c \
                   optionobjclass.c \


LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog 
LOCAL_MODULE:= optplugin
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

the optplugin.c files throws many undefined reference to methods that are implemented in optionobjclass.c

I would appreciate any kind of help.

The declaration in optplugin.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#include "pluginHelp.h"
#include "npapi.h"
#include "npruntime.h"
//#include "npupp.h"
#include "mcvdebug.h"
//#include "jritypes.h"
//#include "gogi_plugin_api.h"          /* GOGI Deprecated */
#include "optionobjclass.c"
#include "optionsClass.h"
#include "IOlsOptionObject.h"
#include "npunix.c"
#define TRACESYMBOL(...) extern int a;
#define TraceDebug(m, ...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

Comment: Did you include the header optionobjectclass.h in optplugin.c? Please add some code from both file.

Comment: Yes, the header files are all present.

Comment: Is it undefinied reference or multiple definition of functions?

Comment: Mostly undefined references. I do have a few multiple definition errors, too.

Comment: Please add your error log for undefined references. post my ans for multiple definitions error.

Answer (score 3):

The multiple definition errors are occured because you are compiling `optionobjclass.c` multiple times.

> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := optplugin.c \
>
> ```
>                   optionobjclass.c \
> ```

and

> #include "optionobjclass.c"

When you includ a source file, the source file will be compiled. The solution is remove `optionobjclass.c` from `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

But the better way is to make heder file `optionobjectclass.h` from `optionobjclass.c` and include the header.

Answer (score 0):

try adding C PLUS PLUS flag, it might be using c++ compiler if any c++ code is present.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```